# how to set timeout for progress bar script

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, progress-bar, html

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
    //Raised before processing of an asynchronous postback starts and the postback request is sent to the server.
    prm.add_beginRequest(BeginRequestHandler);
    // Raised after an asynchronous postback is finished and control has been returned to the browser.
    prm.add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);
    function BeginRequestHandler(sender, args) {
        //Shows the modal popup - the update progress
        var popup = $find('<%= modalPopup.ClientID %>');
        if (popup != null) {
            popup.show();


        }
    }
    function EndRequestHandler(sender, args) {
        //Hide the modal popup - the update progress
        var popup = $find('<%= modalPopup.ClientID %>');
       if (popup != null) {
           popup.hide();               


       }
   }

</script>
```

Comment: Please do explain what exactly not working or where you exactly in the line of code you need help.

Comment: I get error  0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerTimeoutException: The server request timed 
and progress bar stop its working but process is still continue @Mr_Green

Comment: Thanx i got solution  set timeout AsyncPostBackTimeout="50000"

 <cc1:ToolkitScriptManager runat="server" AsyncPostBackTimeout="50000"></cc1:ToolkitScriptManager>

Answer (score 0):

i got solution.

set timeout AsyncPostBackTimeout="50000" in ToolkitScriptManager or ScriptManager